# Will a program exit when the main thread exits?

Tags: java

I have two threads: the main thread and a thread started from the main thread.

When the main thread exits, will the whole program terminate?

Comment: If any thread call System.exit() the program can exit, however if all main does is return, non daemon threads will keep the application running.

Comment: For something well defined like this you really should try it out first; you'd get the answer, and if you still had a question you could post a code snippet that would make the discussion more valuable for others who had the same question.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No.

Java programs terminate when all non-daemon threads finish.

The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) states:

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up,
>   there is usually a single non-daemon
>   thread (which typically calls the
>   method named main of some designated
>   class). The Java Virtual Machine
>   continues to execute threads until
>   either of the following occurs:
>
> - The `exit` method of class `Runtime` has been called and the
>     security manager has permitted the
>     exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning
>     from the call to the `run` method or
>     by throwing an exception that
>     propagates beyond the `run` method.

If you don't want the runtime to wait for a thread, call the [`setDaemon` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 2):

No.
Main Thread is Non-Demon thread, unless your child thread is demon thread, Program will not terminate even if main thread finishes before child thread. You can check that using below sample program.

```
public class app {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    App2.mt=Thread.currentThread();
    App2 t = new App2();
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Main starts");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Main ends");

  }
}

class App2 extends Thread{
static Thread mt;
public void run(){
    try {
        mt.join();//waits till main thread dies.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("child thread");
  }
}
```