# How to check that main method has finished execution?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to see whether main method has finished execution or not with reference to this question [link] ([How can child threads still executes even after if their parent thread dies or terminates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163922/how-can-child-threads-still-executes-even-after-if-their-parent-thread-dies-or-t).Kindly) tell me the java code to see that main method has finished execution.Please don't tell me this using daemon threads because I don't wanna use daemon Threads.

Comment: "tell me the java code .." ? tell me your code please.

Comment: This is the link to my code [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163922/how-can-child-threads-still-executes-even-after-if-their-parent-thread-dies-or-t).

Comment: @Ankit Downvoting some question doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: If you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642802/termination-of-program-on-main-thread-exit evidently the application does NOT terminate after the main function terminates. The way to make sure main thread is the last is to use `join()` on all the other threads from the main thread. This way main only finishes after all the other threads finish.

Comment: There is not a parent-child relationship between threads in a JVM.  If you want your main method to wait for other threads you must explicitly code that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tell me the java code to see that main method has finished execution.

How about this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Do stuff ...
    System.err.println("The main method has finished");
}
```

If that is not what you want, you need to be more clear and specific with your Question.

Comment: This is the link to my code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163922/how-can-child-threads-still-executes-even-after-if-their-parent-thread-dies-or-t) I wanna see when main method() dies.

Comment: @TruePS - Well this will tell you that.

Comment: @ Stephen So you are implying that child threads still keeps running if there parent thread that is main method() dies.

Comment: @TruePS - No. I'm not implying anything.  I'm just answering your question.  However, what you propose *is a true statement*.

Comment: So that statement is true " child threads still keeps running if there parent thread that is main method() die"

Comment: @TruePS - Yes.  When the parent terminates, the children do not *automatically* terminate as well.  But you don't need to write a whole bunch of code to know that.  You could read what the javadocs say about the behaviour of threads ...

Answer (score 0):

If it is just out of interest, Use a debugger to see all the threads of your program.

And please don't mix up thread models. The article you refer to in the other question is about a threading framework for `C++`. There even exist different threading models for `C`/`C++` on a single system, so always make sure to read about the one you are actually using.

Comment: I am using Netbeans Could you please tell me how to use a debugger to see all the threads of your program.I have never done it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn how to start your program in debug mode, and then learn to set break points

Comment: Set a breakpoint int `main()`, then right click your main class and select "Debug As Java Application". You can then open the thread view by selecting "View/Debugging/Threads".