# Java MultiThreaded arrays are not outputing into console

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

So for my program is supposed to print out the arrays I have using multithreading, I do not know why isn't outputting into the console, but I have an idea that it is in my getters and setters, but I have looked around and haven't found a solution. Here is my code.

```
public class multithreadTest{

 private static class Test implements Runnable{  
  private String [] questions;
  private String [] answers;
  private String [] category;

  public Test(String[] questions, String[] answers, String[] category){
      this.questions = questions;
      this.answers = answers;
      this.category = category;
   }
  public String[] getQuestions(){ return this.questions;}
  public String[] getAnswers(){return this.answers;}
  public String[] getCategory(){return this.category;}

  public void run(){
      System.out.println("Q: " + questions[1] + "A: " + answers[1] + "C: " +    category[1]);
}
 }

 public static void main(String[]args){
   String [] questions = new String[100];
   String [] answers = new String[100];
   String [] category = new String[100];

try{
     File file = new File("Questionbank.txt");

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

      int l = 0;

      while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String [] words = line.split("::");

        questions[l] = words[0];
        answers[l] = words[1];
        category[l] = words[2];
        //System.out.println("Q: " + Questions[l] + "A: " + Answers[l] + "C: " + Category[l]);
           l++;

     }
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}


  Thread t = new Thread(new Test(questions,answers,category));
  t.start();
 }
```

}

Comment: Please read this first: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: And you need to `t.join();` to wait on `t`'s termination. Otherwise, it might be that the main thread terminates before the auxiliary thread has even started.

Comment: Using raw threads has become an antipattern about 10 years ago. Look into ExecutorServices for more modern idioms: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html

Comment: Some remarks on your code: - Class names should always start with an uppercase letter - Your indentation is terrible. You should fix it. - Write the array-brackets directly after the type (`String []` -> `String[]`) - Arrays in Java are 0-based, not 1-based (there is no acutal bug in your program, but your programming lead me to the conclusion that you might think that arrays are 1-based) - When you use closeable resources, close them. If you use them within a `try`-block, use a [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: @Turing85 I doubt the main thread would exit before launching the new thread. Doesn't seem like desirable behavior to force the main thread to wait for the auxillary thread to finish, let alone force it to wait until the auxillary thread starts producing results. Then again, I could be wrong, haven't read the spec for this.

Comment: @VinceEmigh you seem to be right (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642802/termination-of-program-on-main-thread-exit))

Comment: Alright, thanks for the quick responses, I'll try these out